# Magento Complex Attribute: Value(s) = (Drop-Down item + Text Field input), and need an "Add Another" button

Tags: php, magento, entity-attribute-value

I'm in the early stages of planning and developing a Magento-based site. My company carries around 20,000 items.

One of the most valuable features on our current site is the ability to cross-reference our items based on our competitor's item number. Any one item of ours can have between 0 and 30+ Competitor Cross-References. I need to figure out how to achieve this feature in Magento.

What I'd like to do is configure a 2-part attribute that is searchable, but not displayed on the product's page, and be able to have a varying number of values. In the Add Product Page, it would look sorta like this:

Cross Reference(s): [Drop Down of Competitor Company Names] + [Textfield For Competitor Part No.] (+ Button to Add Another Cross Reference)

It doesn't look like there's any way to do this with Magento out-of-the-box in the Admin interface, so I'm ready to extend the core with a module of my own. I've started digging around in the 10,000 files that make up a Magento install; but I could really use some help on this.

Thanks in advance to any who read and reply!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Custom Options. Maybe a simple solution would be to put the CompanyName & PartNo in the same option and later (once you have Magento experience!) make a custom interface to make it easier to administer (with the dropdowns).